# Java factory uses generics and Supplier interface, but still needs typecasts, something is not right

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to use generics and a Supplier to avoid needing to typecast the result of my static factory method but failing. I think I'm close, can someone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Here is the parameterized interface *IManager*:

```
public interface IManager<C extends IConfigObject> {
```

Here is an abstract base class *AbstractManager*, which includes the static factory method:

```
public abstract class AbstractManager<C extends IConfigObject> implements IManager<C> {
    ....
    public static  <C extends IConfigObject> AbstractManager<C> getInstance(Supplier<? extends AbstractManager<C>> supplier) {
```

Next, here is a concrete implementation called *MyManager* which is parameterized with *MyConfigObject*, which in turn implements *IConfigObject*:

```
public final class MyManager extends AbstractManager<MyConfigObject> {
```

And finally, the main() code:

```
Supplier<MyManager> supplier = MyManager::new;
MyManager manager = (MyManager) AbstractManager.getInstance(supplier);
```

If I don't have the cast in there, I get a compiler error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from
>   AbstractManager to MyManager

Any suggestions?

Comment: Things you've not defined: interface `IConfigObject`, interface `IAgentApiManager`, local variable `agentApiManagerFactory`.

Comment: Shouldn't the return type be `AbstractManager<MyConfigObject>`?

Comment: Sorry was editing out some things for brevity/clarity, I'll fix the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here: `Supplier<? extends AbstractManager<C>>`. By using the wildcard, you're saying "I don't care about the actual type" but you do.

The key here is to first use two type parameters, the second of which relies on the first one (I used `M` for "manager"):

```
public static <C extends IConfigObject, M extends AbstractManager<C>>
    M getInstance(Supplier<M> supplier)
{
    // ...
}
```

If you're not using `C` in the method body, you could refactor it to:

```
public static <M extends AbstractManager<? extends IConfigObject>>
    M getInstance(Supplier<M> supplier)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: By the way, [try to avoid creating objects that end in -er](https://www.yegor256.com/2015/03/09/objects-end-with-er.html).

Comment: Why that (ends in -er) ?

Comment: I've changed the getInstance method as follows:  public static  <C extends IConfigObject, M extends AbstractManager<C>> AbstractManager<C> getInstance(Supplier<M> supplier) {

Comment: But now get the compiler error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from AbstractManager<MyConfigObject> to MyManager

Comment: @RichardSand You didn't copy my example properly. The return type must be `M`.

Comment: Sorry Michael - I didn't even notice that your comment was a link to an article. I will read it though

Comment: Right you are, sir! Thank you very much, that did the trick - no more typecasts!

Comment: @RichardSand Sure, happy to help.